# .net equivilent of Delphi's QuotedStr function

Tags: c#, .net, delphi

Does .net have the equivilent of Delphi's QuotedStr function. This replaces all quotes with two quote characters and then adds a quote to the start and the end, e.g.

Lets assume the varaible s holds the string:

```
Welcome to Steve's Store
```

then `QuotedStr(s)` would return:

```
'Welcome to Steve''s Store'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
"'" + str.Replace("'", "''") + "'"
```

Comment: No this has nothing to do with SQL

Comment: Thanks, so there is no built in function?

Comment: Yes there is no in built function

Comment: You can however create a help extension method for this assuming you're using .Net 3.5 +

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Use QuotedStr to convert the string S to a quoted string. 
/// A single quotation mark (') is inserted at the beginning and end of S, 
/// and each single quotation mark in the string is repeated. 
/// </summary>
String QuotedStr(String s)
{
    //Note: All code on stackoverflow is public domain; no attribution required.

    //Handle the case when s is null.
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return "''";
   
    return "'" + s.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
```